# How to compare text field with save contacts

Tags: android

I am making an android dialing application in which I added 4 tabs. In the fourth tab I am saving contacts.

Now, I want that when I dial a number on the keypad to display the save contacts in the list which is matching with the dialed number:

[image]

Comment: do NOT use irrelevant tags to attract attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by using AutoCompleteTextView. You should get your contacts in a list or an array and add them to the AutoCompleteTextView then when you start typing, it filters contacts and shows the matching results in a list.

here you are the xml for it

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/numbers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

and the code for putting elements in it

```
// the array of strings which will be given to the view
String[] numbers = {"123456", "234567", "345678"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, numbers);
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
             findViewById(R.id.numbers);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

check developer's documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: but putting it in xml it is over writting with my text field

Comment: Yes this should replace your text field, as the usual EditText can't do the job

Comment: But when I want to dial number what  I will do

Comment: in this photo the steps on choosing an element
http://up.harajgulf.com/do.php?img=141937

when you start typing it shows the matching result, you select the one you want by clicking on it then it's written in the text field
then you do the rest of your code to dial.